# Inequality from Selberg's proof of the PNT

Tags: number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

Selberg states the incorrect inequality
$$\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{\log p}{x}=\log x+O(1)$$
that of course refers to the inequality
$$\sum_{p\leq x}\frac{\log p}{p}=\log x+O(1)\tag*{(1.4)}$$
and says that by partial summation this implies
$$\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\vartheta(n)}{n^2}=\log x+O(1).\tag*{(1.5)}$$

The last inequality "(1.5)" is correct, however I have tried already using "partial summation" with (1.4), which I think means Abel's summation formula, as
$$\sum_{1<n\leq x}\frac{\vartheta(n)}{n}\frac{1}{n}$$ but this gives me an incorrect relation. I may be doing something wrong but I have already tried some different setups and none seem to work. Can anyone give me a hint on what to do?

Comment: What have you done specifically?

Comment: Apply Abel's summation formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel's_summation_formula) with $a(t)=\vartheta(t)/t$ and $f(n)=1/n$, that gives the sum that I want to get $\sum \vartheta(n)/n^2$, but it gives me incorrect bounds, I also tried with different $a$ and $f$ (I will try to look if I can find my work, but it was a similar variation that gave me a different answer).

Comment: Have you tried letting $a(n)=\begin{cases}\log n & n\text{ prime}\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ and $f(n)=1/n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From partial summation, we can convert (1.4) into an integral:

$$
\sum_{p\le x}{\log p\over p}={\vartheta(x)\over x}+\int_2^x{\vartheta(t)\over t^2}\mathrm dt=\int_2^x{\vartheta(t)\over t^2}\mathrm dt+O(1).
$$

For the integral, notice that for $n\ge2$,

$$
\int_n^{n+1}{\vartheta(t)\over t^2}\mathrm dt=\vartheta(n)\int_n^{n+1}{\mathrm dt\over t^2}={\vartheta(n)\over n^2}\left\{1+O\left(\frac1n\right)\right\}={\vartheta(n)\over n^2}
+O(1),
$$

so we have

$$
\int_2^x{\vartheta(t)\over t^2}\mathrm dt=\sum_{n\le x}{\vartheta(n)\over n^2}+O(1).
$$

Combining everything gives the desired result.

Comment: I see it till before asserting that
$$\int_n^{n+1}\frac{1}{t^2}dt=\frac{1}{n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right) $$
isn't it just $1/(n^2+n)=O(1/n^2)$?

Comment: Ok sorry haha I see it. However I cannot see how the last equation gives us what we want.
I mean, we would need 
$$\int_2^x\frac{\vartheta(t)}{t^2}dt=\log x+O(1)$$
and since $\vartheta(x)=O(x)$ then $\vartheta(x)=x+R(x)$ with $R(x)=O(x)$ so that the integral would be $\log x+O(\int 1/t dt )=\log x+O(\log x)$ but then how do we just get $O(1)$? Maybe I'm not seein something

Comment: Just use (1.4) in your question

Comment: Thanks, that's true